# How can I update the development version Google Chrome?

Tags: software-center, update-manager, google-chrome

I am running Ubuntu Maverick under VMWare on Windows to make sure the code I write works on various OSes and browsers. I don't use it as my primary operating system.

I can't figure out how to update Google Chrome dev channel I installed a while ago.

- I can't do it via the "About Google Chrome" like in Windows.
- Update manager lists 317 MB of updates and doesn't seem to let me search them or deselect or. They are not even in alphabetical order but I can't see Chrome in there.
- Ubuntu Software Centre under Get Software/Google/google-chrome-unstable/More Info says "Version: 12.0.725-r80304" which would be the latest, but running Crhome, the "About Google Chrome" dialog tells me it is "11.0.686.1 dev"

What am I doing wrong? By the way is "unstable" a synonym for "dev" in Google Chrome. Ubuntu Software Centre only lists "beta", "stable", and "unstable" but not "dev".

Comment: This question is Complete mess. You have chrome UNstable and we All have google stable !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Google Chrome in updated in Ubuntu via normal system update.
The Unstable channel is actually the DEV Channel of Google Chrome.

Go to **System** -> **Administration** -> **Update Manager** and update your system and the Google Chrome would be updated to latest DEV release.

Or to selectively upgrade Google Chrome, run this command from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-unstable
```

Comment: I think you missed my middle point about 317 MB of updates. I have to pay for very slow internet here and don't need all that stuff. But I did figure out how to disable all the other updates so I'll accept your answer thank you (-:

Comment: Yes I did missed your second point. You can use sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome

Comment: @Jorge +1 for your observation, though I usually let update-manager do its work in updating packages :-)

Comment: This question is Complete mess. You have chrome UNstable and we All have google stable !

Comment: Why one should upgrade to an unstable version?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha to have new features faster. Sometimes it's better to have some feature faster and start developing and switch to stable chrome when that feature reaches stable channel then wait.

Answer (score 13):

For me what worked is:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-stable
```

(instead of *unstable*)

Comment: I had to run sudo apt-get update first

Answer (score 2):

In an attempt to make this out-of date question useful, Currently Chrome supports a number of different release channels. For Ubuntu Linux as of the date of writing these are:

[**Stable Channel:**](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?platform=linux)  This channel has gotten the full testing and blessing of the Chrome test team, and is the best bet to avoid crashes and other issues.  It's updated roughly every two-three weeks for minor releases, and every 6 weeks for major releases.

[**Beta Channel:**](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html?platform=linux) If you are interested in seeing what's next, with minimal risk, Beta channel is the place to be.  It's updated every week roughly, with major updates coming every six weeks, more than a month before the Stable channel will get them.

[**Dev Channel:**](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?platform=linux&extra=devchannel) Want to see what's happening quickly, then you want the Dev channel.  The Dev channel gets updated once or twice weekly, and it shows what we're working on right now.  There's no lag between major versions, whatever code we've got, you will get.  While this build does get tested, it is still subject to bugs, as we want people to see what's new as soon as possible.

Source:

[Chrome Release Channels](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing a similar problem and wanted to upgrade Chrome from Version 65.0.3325.162 to the latest stable version.
The command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-stable
```

upgrades *all* the packages installed in the system including Chrome.

If you only want to upgrade your Chrome version to the latest stable, you should run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

This will install the latest stable version of Chrome if you do not have it installed. Otherwise, if you already have an older version installed in your system, it will automatically upgrade Chrome to the latest version. This way you can surely save on data.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade google-chrome-stable
```

Try this one out. It will also update remaining software on Ubuntu.