# Update to chrome 51?

Tags: updates, 16.04, google-chrome, update-manager

How to update **chrome 49** to **chrome 51**? I searched on the Internet and found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/33745/464430) , I tried it but it didn't solve my problem. On windows I had only to go to about and find the new update. Any help please ?

Comment: Apparently you have somehow removed (or disabled) the Chrome repository from the package system. Why not just download and install the latest Chrome version? It's probably the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: Could it be that you are running a 32-bit computer and/or a 32-bit Ubuntu? To check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os If that's the case: Google has discontinued support for its 32-bit Chrome as seen here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued. You will need to switch your browser. For example chromium-browser: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [Chrome 51](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) form the link and its download an `deb` file.

So open it via Ubuntu Software Center and install it.

---

**Update 2018-05-21**

use

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the ***terminal*** and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the update is available in Ubuntu, it should install after executing these commands.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this it's in comments of answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
Google Chrome is not available in ubuntu stable repo.
There is two way to solve the update issue based upon how you installed google chrome.

1. Most people downloads .deb file from https://www.google.com/chrome install it inthat case you have to download and install .deb file again
2. There is a stable version of google chrome available on 3rd party repo
   if you had installed it from that then you can simply do

   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade